# Videos are not playing properly

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, video

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop having ati amd radeon graphics card.But in Ubuntu I experience lots of trouble like the videos are not playing flawlessly. sometimes it stucks.
I used every graphics drivers in additional drivers list. I install Ubuntu restricted extra. but nothing help me. please anyone help me to do this thing right.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubunty. Please be as precise as possible in your question title as well as your question. As it is, "videos not playing properly" is too general to attract useful answers.

Comment: Try different players. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) is good alternative to totem.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: You probably are missing the proper codecs for the videos you are trying to play. Maybe review this website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats